# Stripe subscriptions and React - Safe to have key on client? when and how to collect credit card info?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am following this guide here: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart

I have done step 1 and 2 and am on to step 3 - Step 3: Subscribe the customer to the plan.

How and when in these steps do I collect the users credit card information in react? What step is that?

Is it safe to expose my production stripe key on the client when doing this on the client side in a react component?:

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");

const subscription = stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer: 'cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a',
  items: [{plan: 'plan_CBXbz9i7AIOTzr'}],
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you definitely don't want to put your `sk_live` key on the client. That's a big security problem.

My solution for Stripe payments with React was to build a simple Node/Express API server to communicate with clients in a RESTful way.

Basically, you put the publishable (the `pk_live` key) Stripe key on the client, and the secret (the `sk_live` key) Stripe key on your API server.

Then, you make POST requests from the client to your API server to create charges, create customers, etc.

Comment: Ah I only saw one key on my dashboard, didn't realise there were two. So what is the checkout flow? At the moment I create a stripe client and store it in my database when someone signs up, I created the subscription plan on dashboard, now how do I collect their credit card details and attach it to the client id and start the subscription plan?

Comment: stripe.subscriptions.create doesn't seem to collect credit card information, so I need to create the client id and subscription plan id, use these two ids together to create the subscription,  but I also need to collect credit card information for that client id so theres something to pay the subscription. Not sure on the flow

Comment: You create a form on the client side for credit card number, expiration, etc. Then, when a user inputs that data, you send it directly to Stripe. Stripe will return a token for that credit card to the client. Then, when the credit card token from Stripe hits the client, you can send that token to your API server. You can use that token to create a "source" for the customer, which is basically a way to charge the customer. You can use that source (on your API server, not client), to subscribe the customer to a subscription. Client: get the token. API server: create source and subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

The important part to understand from this is that EVERYTHING you send on the client side is not secure. Even if you minify your javascript, you still send the key in a plain text format. You should never send any private key to the front-end.

The key, like tsteve mentionned, is to build something that is external to your front-end. You can use HTTP Request and build yourself a RESTful API, use websockets, or even go with a serverless solution. This works because your client only receive your front-end files.